# Mail client for multiple accounts with web ui

Tags: email-client, saas, web-apis

We are a small community with a forum, a chat and a website. For better organization of our team and the respective roles of its members, we need a web-based email client<sup>1</sup>. These are our must-haves:

- Multiple accounts per team member (name@, group@, etc.)
- web based
- not a full, self-hosted mail server
- configurable (for example with an API)
- free version until we reach a certain limit (max emails or the like)

Is there something, you could recommend to us?

---

<sup>1</sup> The service that we're looking for is a mail server that we don't want to manage ourselves due to—despite being developers—having few experiences in the mail server segment and not having the time to maintain a full mail server. (Sorry if my choice of words is confusing. This can be because I'm not a native speaker.)

Comment: Sorry but your description is totally contradictory. Are you really searching for an mail server UI or just a communication software for a closed user group (something like Slack or MS teams but for a local installation)?

Comment: Definitely not local on the user's computer. It should be web-based. We are looking for some kind of mail server as a SaaS solution to reduce maintanance on our side in comparision to hosting an entire mail server on our own. The inboxes are for a closed user group that should be dynamically configurable in some kind of backend.

Comment: When it come to "local" regarding a server software of course a your server is meant. You can also call it "on premise" just in difference to "in the cloud". So do you already have a running mail server?

Comment: Oh, okay. No, it should not be on premise unless just the frontend were on premise so no, we need something cloud-based.